# I changed my package name, but it only changed the gen folder name, not the src

Tags: android, package

I changed my package name, but it only changed the gen folder name, not the src. when I go to change the src folder it warns me that there is already a folder with this name...

Edit: I found I had errors in my manifest file! fixed those and everything was fine

Comment: Exit Eclipse, roll back/reset in your version control, open Eclipse again and use the refactor functionality.

Comment: Yeah, restart Eclipse. Also, refresh the Eclipse project explorer.

Comment: Since you deleted the question I'll comment here... in your answers tab in your profile page you should see "deleted recent answers" link. Click it. See if you can improve any of the deleted answers, do it then: A) if you deleted it yourself simply click undelete B) if it was deleted by others flag choose "other" and explain you improved thus asking to undelete. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is there was a problem in my manifest file, causing everything not to compile.
if you see crazy errors that seem not reasonable, try this solution. there is probably something wrong with your manifest file. for me it was a wrong package name in the manifest after changing the package name.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's one of many things I hate about eclipse... you should restart eclipse, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a Project > Clean. That helps in most cases if restarting doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is such a bad utility. Anyhow, you could either restart the whole thing or start over.